# How do you put ruby inside a javascript function, google maps?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have a ruby on rails app that has a google map with a marker on it that when you click it it opens an info window using javascript. I want to put ruby var in this javascript fn that displays info from the database in the window.

So when the user clicks the marker they get dynamic info from database not just generic text from js fn.

If anyone has done this before I'd appreciate if you could tell me how you did it , thanks

Comment: Do you want the information from Ruby embedded directly in the page, or is AJAX an option? (The JavaScript making a web request to the server)

Comment: check the gmaps4rails source code

Answer (score 2):

You can put your javascript directly on your html.erb file using  tag and run embedded ruby code within the javascript. Remember to escape_javascript because sometimes your variables will mess up your script by some special characters like apostrophes.

```
<script>
  alert(<%= escape_javascript @variable %>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edward's solution of processing your Javascript files with erb will work (though you will have to remember to add .erb to the end of your JS file so that ERB knows to process it... ie maps.js.erb).

The thing is, this is contrary to the philosophy of the asset pipeline as I understand it. Rails purposely concatenates all your Javascript into one file to save on the overhead of HTTP requests. More importantly, however, browsers cache this file so they do not need to refetch it on every request. If you have a variable that changes the JS file depending on the request made, Rails needs to reprocess the JS file for every request, which is expensive. (Note that the same concept applies to CSS).

The best solution I have found is to put the variable value in the page somehow, since this is one file that needs to be dynamically processed on every request. Usually I see people putting them in hidden forms, as such:

```
<%= content_tag :input, nil, :type => 'hidden', :id => "map-name-field", :'data-name' => @map.name %>
```

One approach I have also used is to attach it to an element on the page which is unique to that page, such as a name or title:

```
<%= content_tag :h2, @map.name, :id => "map-name", :'data-name' => @map.name %>
```

Once it's on the page, you can fetch from within your JS function (but the key here is that the fetcher function is the same for all isntances of your map, and thus does not need to change or reprocess the JS file):

```
// Assuming jQuery
// For the hidden input approach:
var mapName = $('#map-name-field').value
// or for the data-attribute approach:
var mapName = $('#map-name').attr('data-name')
```